# Compare date with current_date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I can not get what is wrong in this query ( ORACLE QUERY )

```
SELECT *
FROM HR.CUSTOMER C
dual
WHERE CREATED_AT = current_date
;
```

I am getting this error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: remove `dual` and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `dual` too many in your query.

Moreover, in Oracle `current_date` is not the current date for the database, but the current datetime of your session. While your database server may be in a timezone where it is currently 11 p.m., it may be next day 3 a.m. already on your PC. Whenever you spot `current_date` in an Oracle query it is very likely wrong.

In Oracle use `sysdate` for now and `trunc(sysdate)` for today.

```
select * 
from hr.customer 
where created_at = trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: Hi Thorsten, there is a CURRENT_DATE function in Oracle but it returns the current date and time  according to the time zone of the client. SYSDATE returns the current date in the server timezone. But given that the field is called "CREATED_AT" I hope it is better filled with the SYSDATE to make it consistent across different timezones.
Best regards Felix

Comment: @fhossfel: Thanks Felix, I didn't know that. So `CURRENT_DATE` does exist, but it's not likely we want to use it here. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Although comments explain that, I still think this answer is worth editing, because it's confusing at first glance.

Comment: @Line: Thank you. You are right. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the table and wanted to get all the columns from it, you need not use dual

> The DUAL table is a special one-row, one-column table present by
>   default in Oracle and other database installations. In Oracle, the
>   table has a single VARCHAR2(1) column called DUMMY that has a value of
>   'X'. It is suitable for use in selecting a pseudo column such as
>   SYSDATE or USER.

You may just use the following query instead

```
SELECT *
  FROM HR.CUSTOMER
 WHERE CREATED_AT = current_date;
```